# Jsf- primefaces MouseEvent or alternative solution

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2, primefaces

I have use a graphic image that can be draggable in a outputpanel. I want know where the mouse is in that outputpanel- relatively hight of that outputpanel- and I want to compute percentage of outputpanel where the draggable image is.

How can i do that? I will be thankful, if you advice any solution to handle.

Comment: You should seek the solution purely in the client side, thus the relevant tags are HTML and CSS, not JSF or PF. Attach an appropriate function handler to HTML4 mous... / HTML5 drag... events and do the necessary job, notifying the server when needed.